# Eclipse exits with error "JVM terminated..."

Tags: eclipse

Every time eclipse is closed, it pops up a error message like this:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/kaiyin/opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/kaiyin/opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0.v20130605-2000/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/kaiyin/opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/kaiyin/opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416/eclipse_1506.so
-startup /home/kaiyin/opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 1f60014
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/kaiyin/opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

I am running it on a kubuntu 13.04 machine, it's installed from the official website (not ubuntu repository), here is version info:

```
Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: If you run eclipse from the command line (not double-clicking on the icon) are there errors that are sent to the console?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this when the bitness of eclipse doesn't match the bitness of your java install.  It looks like you have the 64-bit version of eclipse.

If you run `java -version` does it say something like this:

```
paulw@desktop:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I have added java version info to my question.

Comment: I did a `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to switch to openjdk-6, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are under linux version maybe ubuntu or others, if you met such question i hope this solution can help you out.

**First**:open `eclipse.ini` and find the `-startup` jar file, and `run java -jar ***.jar`, if there are errors, you can go to `configuration folder` and find the latest log file.

**Second**:read the log file and maybe you can see these logs:

```
!SESSION 2016-11-14 10:41:29.823 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20161027-0700
java.version=1.7.0_79
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US

This is a continuation of log file /home/crabime/Documents/eclipse/configuration/1479091290264.bak_1.log
Created Time: 2016-11-14 10:41:40.161

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.js.npm 2 0 2016-11-14 10:41:40.161
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.js.npm [857]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.109.0.v20161017-1617"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui [773]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-version="[3.10.100,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-version="3.13.0.v20161022-1508"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.jface [407]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.swt; bundle-version="[3.104.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.swt; bundle-version="3.106.0.v20161027-0130"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.swt [760]                   
                        Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
```

and you can see the last line, `required jdk version is 1.8`, so no matter you change the `vmargs requiredJavaVersion` to 1.7 or others, make no sense.

**Third**:if you think the second way is too sophistic, you can also read the `readme.html` under readme folder.And here i find something useful :

> In general, the 4.6 release of the Eclipse Project is developed on Java SE 8 VMs. As such, the Eclipse SDK as a whole is targeted at all modern, desktop Java VMs.

And my eclipse version is 4.7 you can see from the second log file, so `without other entry and download jdk 1.8`.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded *.gz instead of *.rpm from Oracle site. 
I used jdk version 7u40 64bit.
After that problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This issue mainly comes when the default jdk used by eclipse is having 
some problem. So better manually download the package and set the environment variable 
details can be found [here](http://ubuntudabblersblog.blogspot.in/2011/09/installing-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-1.html)