# My eclipse didn't run it display this message when i clicked on it

Tags: eclipse

[image: Eclipse Problem]

Eclipse didn't runs display this message what can i do kindly help me..
I have Kepler but when i download Eclipse Luna and runs it this error comes..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse exits with error "JVM terminated..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050878/eclipse-exits-with-error-jvm-terminated)

Comment: -clean command didn't work for me..

Comment: Kindly help me i have jdk1.8.0_31. I am using windows 8. How can i solve this problem.

Comment: are you running 64-bit eclipse on 32-bit machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4587518/2670892

Comment: No 64-bit eclipse on 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

You should restart Eclipse with the `-clean` command line option, it usually fixes the issue.

Another possible solution:

Change your `eclipse.ini` and specify the full JVM path with the `-vm` argument. For example:

```
-vm C:/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

**Update:** take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587518/eclipses-error-on-startup-in-windows-7), this may be useful.